# Show/Hide button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I want to show/hide the button with class ".edit-one-button" within ".widget" by using the javascript below. However, the button is not hidden when I first load the page. Any idea what might went wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('.edit-one-button').hide();  
      $('.widget').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.edit-one-button').fadeIn(100);
      }, function () {
        $(this).find('.edit-one-button').fadeOut(100);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Good question. Not that either. The button shows up when I first load that page. The hover effect doesn't work either...

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library? Do you get any Javascript errors in the error console?

Comment: I included that. I do have an error which is saying another function was not built successfully. Will that affect this part???

Comment: check your class names, - what do you get when you type " $('.edit-one-button')" in the console?

Comment: That's what I got: [input.edit-one-button Edit, input.edit-one-button Edit, input.edit-one-button Edit, input.edit-one-button Edit]

Comment: Hmmm, there was a plugin affecting that. Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

You could also reverse the code so `.edit-one-button` has an inline style of display:none then add a class like `.active` on hover with `display:block` in the css rather than hide on load using javascript.

```
.edit-one-button {
  display:none;
}



$(function () { 
  $('.widget').hover(function () {
    $('.widget .edit-one-button').fadeIn(100);
  }, function () {
    $('.widget .edit-one-button').fadeOut(100);
  });
});
```

Comment: The OP's code already is in document ready.  They are using the `$(fn)` version which works the same as `$(document).ready(fn)`.

Comment: Still still good practice. The CSS solution I proposed is also relevant and would work.

Comment: The code *is* already in the ready event. The op is using the shorthand.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that using the other way you mentioned? So it will all be done through css instead of javascript?

Comment: @wcdomy: It can't all be done using CSS. You can't change the style for one element by hovering another element.

Comment: Chris, you don't seem to understand that the OP's code is already using `document.ready()`.  They are using a shorthand version.  Your code example does not change anything - It's functionally equivalent to what the OP has.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. Give me a couple mins and I'll update a way to do this.

Comment: I guess the code itself has nothing wrong. Must be some issues elsewhere. I don't think the function is even called.

Comment: Removed the downvote as the answer is not misleading now, but it still doesn't fix anything in the original code, it's just another way to do the same thing.